# How to make a parallax background for indefinite page height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a website that uses a parallax background, the background is `1200px` long.

The issue is:
I have a page with indefinite height, the page get expanded dynamically to its content. So if a user press read more it expands without refresh, which ruin the parallax effect because the background reaches its end before the page finish.

The background is complex design image, it cannot be repeated and adding background-color to cover up the white space cant be done, but I wish I can keep the cool parallax effect!

My question:
Is it possible to make the parallax stop when it reaches a specific y-position, and freezes the background when scrolling beyond the specific y position? But also to be able to trigger on the parallax effect when scrolling back to the specific y-position and above?

If we assume background is moving at 0.1 speed, then the max height will be `1200/0.1 = 12000px`.

If page reaches `y-position = 12000px` -> stop parallax effect and freeze image as is -> and if page return back to `1199px` start parallax again

How to do this in Javascript? If possible in CSS would be great too.

**Edit:**

here is what I did before posting on Stackoverflow:

**I used Stellar.js for the parallax effect, simply i added the following javascript:**

```
$(window).stellar({responsive:false});
```

and added the following code to the  tag (which hold the background-image):

```
<body data-stellar-background-ratio="0.1">
```

**I also tried another approach, by using a custom JavaScript I found in the web:**

```
    $( window ).scroll( function(){
      var ypos = $( window ).scrollTop(); //pixels the site is scrolled down
      var visible = $( window ).height(); //visible pixels
      const img_height = 1261; //image height
      var max_scroll = img_height - visible; //number of pixels of the image not visible at bottom
    //change position of background-image as long as there is something not visible at the bottom  
    if ( max_scroll > ypos) {
         $('body').css('background-position', "center -" + ypos + "px");
      } else {
        $('body').css('background-position', "center -" + max_scroll + "px");
      }
    });
```

in this case, it do scroll until the end of the background, But I can't figure out how to slow down the scroll speed of the background.

Comment: Can you provide us with a working example that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Yes, it can be done but to help you further, we need to know more details about how you achieve the parallax effect.

Comment: thanks for the replies, please check the edit i made

Comment: Hi guys, any suggestions for my case.. your guidelines will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Does your application run on browsers have CSS `calc` support?